# UIButton Image Not Changing With Interface Builder Settings (Selected & Disabled)

Tags: ios, uibutton, interface-builder

I am trying to set the toggle state of a UIButton through the interface builder. I have done it successfully using code, but I need to get it working through the interface builder.

Im not sure what the issue is  but for selected I set its image to 'flashOn' and for disabled I set it to 'flashOff'

[image]

[image]

When I hold down the image, it shows the 2nd image, but pressing the image does not toggle between these two images.

Im certain it's super simple so if you can suggest what I am missing I would appreciate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A button's selected and disabled states need to be set in code.

Answer (score 1):

Can you show your implementation for when you got desired results through code? I think, from what I can piece together from your question, that you have mixed up the states of the button.

Default - images will display for this button in any state unless another is specified explicitely

Disabled - image will display when button is disabled. (button will not switch from this state through user interaction as it is disabled)

Selected - image will display when the button is selected, which as far as I know is only when you set the button as selected through code.

Highlighted - image will display when you press and hold down on the button

Comment: I think you should describe exactly what you are wanting or show some of your implementation so you can get the answer you need.

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like it does need to be set in code, you can't doing it using IB

Comment: > Selected - image will display when the button is selected, which as far as I know is only when you set the button as selected through code. ::: Again, this is very intelligent and intuitive decision by Apple. Why make it easy?